# How to display zip code from either column?

Tags: sqlite

Not sure how to say this better.

Here's what the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Shops(
  "id" TEXT,
  "name" TEXT,
  "contact:postcode" TEXT,
  "contact:city" TEXT,
  "addr:postcode" TEXT,
  "addr:city" TEXT,
  "contact:phone" TEXT,
  "email" TEXT,
  "website" TEXT
);
```

Some rows have contact:postcode filled, some have "addr:postcode" filled, and yet others have both.

I need to just display a zip code, regardless of which column it comes from.

The following works but obviously doesn't display the zip code:

```
SELECT name FROM Shops WHERE "contact:postcode" IS NOT NULL OR "addr:postcode" IS NOT NULL;
```

Is there a way to grab the zip code and display it with "name"? A sub-SELECT maybe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT name, IFNULL("contact:postcode","addr:postcode") zipcode
FROM Shops;
```